# How to make a function that fills empty rows in one column with the values of those in another column?

Tags: r, function, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I want to make function that takes this data

```
now      changed   before
"12ab"   "yes"     "21ba"
"34de"   "no"      
"56fg"   "yes"     "gf65"
"78hi"   "no"      NA
```

And turn it into

```
now      changed   before
"12ab"   "yes"     "21ba"
"34de"   "no"      "34de"
"56fg"   "yes"     "gf65"
"78hi"   "no"      "78hi"
```

So if before is empty, I want before to take the value of now (with the assumption that if it didn't change, it must have been the same.

I want to use a function as I want to apply it to more column pairs.

I tried this:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
fun <- function(data, x, y) {
     coalesce(case_when(data[[y]] == NA | data[[y]] == '' ~ data[[x]], data[[y]])
}
df[c("before", "before1")] <- map2(c("now", "now1"),c("before", "before1") ~  fun(df, .x, .y))
```

But it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert empty string to NA with `dplyr::na_if` and coalesce with `dplyr::coalesce`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  na_if("") %>% 
  mutate(before = coalesce(before, now))

#    now changed before
# 1 12ab     yes   21ba
# 2 34de      no   34de
# 3 56fg     yes   gf65
# 4 78hi      no   78hi
```

As a function, you could have:

```r
f <- function(data, x, y){
  data %>% 
    na_if("") %>% 
    mutate(before = coalesce({{x}}, {{y}}))
}

f(df, before, now)
```

Comment: I get this error: Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

-- Is that because the na_if doesn't work with all data types?

Comment: I'm not sure, it seems it is not related to `na_if` but to your date conversion. Look at the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/as.POSIX*).

Comment: That's strange, because my data is a postal code. Not a date. as.character should work right?

Comment: Maybe this is due to `na_if` then... you can specify which columns you want to apply `na_if(before, "")`.

Comment: Not sure how you are reading in your data, but `read.csv` has a `na.strings` argument where you can also define blank character strings as `NA`....e.g. `na.strings = c('NA', '', ' ')` to avoid exactly this kind of problem

Comment: @ThetaFC I'm reading it using read_sav

Comment: Maël I get this error: Error in na_if(., before, "") : unused argument ("")

Answer (score 0):

See my comment above about defining `na.strings` when reading in your data.  Then you can use base R to fill in the missing data:

`df$before[is.na(df$before)] <- df$now[is.na(df$before)]`